# Get Username and password from a file and validate (without SQL)

Tags: php

I wanted to create a login form in which the username and password entered are verified against a text file stored content.

My index file **index.php**

```
    <?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

    if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
        header("location:login.php");
        exit;
     }
  ?>

 Congratulation! You have logged into password protected page. <a href="logout.php">Click here</a> to Logout.
```

This will basically get the login form **login.php**

```
            /* Check Login form submitted */    
            if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
                /* Define username and associated password array */
                $logins = array('Alex' => '123456','username1' => 'password1','username2' => 'password2');

                /* Check and assign submitted Username and Password to new variable */
                $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
                $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

                /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */        
                if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
                    /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page  */
                    $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
                    header("location:index.php");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    /*Unsuccessful attempt: Set error message */
                    $msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PHP Login form</title>
        <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>

        <br>
        <form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form">
          <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="Table">
            <?php if(isset($msg)){?>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><h3>Login</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" valign="top">Username</td>
              <td><input name="Username" type="text" class="Input"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">Password</td>
              <td><input name="Password" type="password" class="Input"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="Button3"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Now instead of checking the array for username and password I want to check it against the text file **login.txt** with content

```
    Alex,123456
```

Comment: Great! What is your question?

Comment: So bring in the files contents and build your array.

Comment: As you can see that I am verifying against username and password using the array that I have entered. I don't want the array, rather whenever someone enters the Username and Password, it should verify with the login.txt file.

Comment: @chris85 I tried this, but I am getting error Notice: Undefined variable: Username

Comment: Where? What did you try?

Comment: I am new to PHP, so I used this code and replaced the variables and used ',' instead of "=" from
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php10p7.html

Comment: That's not going to put the `username` as the `key` of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_file_contents()` to load the entire file into memory. Then use `preg_match_all()` to find the occurrences of the username. `preg_match_all('/'.$uname.',(.+)/',$uname, $matches)`. The `$matches` will hold a multi-dimensional array of all the returned results. You will then need to loop through this array to find if there is a matching password for each returned user.
See https://regex101.com/r/PvSo22/1 for example

Comment: I am new to PHP, so sorry but I didn't understand this.
Still I tried 
$file = file_get_contents('login.txt');
preg_match_all('/'.$username.',(.+)/',$username, $matches);

Comment: Sorry - my bad. The following preg_match_all('/'.$username.',(.+)/',$username, $matches); should be preg_match_all('/'.$username.',(.+)/',$file, $matches);